# JavaScriptで変数付きsetterのようなことはできますか？

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptではオブジェクトにsetterを用意すれば代入の操作で複雑な処理が行えますが、

```
var o = {
    set current(a) {
        console.log(a)
    },
};
o.current = 1; //console => 1
```

同じように代入で処理をしたいのですが、プロパティに変数をつけたようにはできないでしょうか。厳密にsyntaxが以下のようである必要はありませんが、`...=...`の形にはしたいです。

```
o.current(2) = 1; //2*1, console => 2
o.current(4) = 1; //4*1, console => 4
o.current(4) = 2; //4*2, console => 8
```

変数は文字列ではない予定なので`Proxy`の`handler.get(target, propertyName, receiver)`では少し試したのではできなさそうでしたが、よくはわかってないです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`()`を付けると関数の呼び出し形式になり、左辺値には使えなくなります。
`[]`で代用するとして、`Proxy` を使うのであれば、`get` ではなく `set` になると思います。

```js
const current_hdl = {
 set: (_, name, val) => {
  console.log(Number(name) * val);
  return true;
 }
};
const current = new Proxy({}, current_hdl);

let o = { current: current }
o.current[2] = 1; //2*1, console => 2
o.current[4] = 1; //4*1, console => 4
o.current[4] = 2; //4*2, console => 8
```

追記: 「変数は文字列ではない」というのが、文字列（プロパティ名）として表現不可能、という意味であれば上記は使えないかもしれませんね。

---

数字を複数渡すとのことなので、やはり packet0 さんの回答のように関数にするしかないですね。
少し一般化し、

```
o.method(right, ...lefts);
```

への構文糖として

```
o.param(...lefts).method = right;
// あるいは
o.method = right;
```

を用意する例です。

```js
let o = {
 param: (...lefts) => {
  function setter(target, name, val){
   target[name](val, ...lefts);
   return true;
  }
  return new Proxy(o, {set: setter});
 },
 get current(){
  return (right, ...lefts) => {
   lefts.push(right);
   console.log(lefts);
  }
 },
 set current(right){
  o.current(right);
 },
};

o.param(1, 2).current = 10; // console => [ 1, 2, 10 ]
o.current(10, 1, 2); // 上と同じ

o.param().current = 10; // console => [ 10 ]
o.current = 10; // 上と同じ
o.current(10); // 上と同じ
```

Comment: 数字を複数わたすので、配列に入れれば文字列へ自動変換でわたせなくはないのですが、できれば文字列のパースはしたくないですね

Answer (score 2):

再帰的にProxyを返して、ジャグ配列みたいな感じにすることはできますね。まあメソッドの引数として渡した方が文字列に変換されることもなくて、実用的な気はしますが。

```js
function create_indexer(callback) {
  const handler = {
    get: (target, name) =>
      new Proxy([...target, name], handler),
    set: (target, name, val) =>
      callback.call(null, [...target, name], val)
  };
  return new Proxy([], handler);
}

let o = {
  test: 0,
  current: create_indexer((args, val) => {
    test = args.reduce((prev, cur) => prev + Number(cur), 0) * val;
    console.log(test);
  })
};

o.current[2] = 1; //2*1, console => 2
o.current[4] = 1; //4*1, console => 4
o.current[4] = 2; //4*2, console => 8
o.current[1][1] = 1; //(1+1)*1, console => 2
o.current[1][3] = 1; //(1+3)*1, console => 4
o.current[1][3] = 2; //(1+3)*2, console => 8
```

Comment: わりとパース速度によってはアリかもしれません

Answer (score 1):

なんか思いついたので

`()`がそのままだと関数になり[左辺値には使えない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/30686/3974)ので、1度オブジェクトを返し、そのsetterで元のオブジェクトを変えればいいかなと。関数の他にsetterがあるので`.v`のような余分な文がつきますが...

```js
var o = {
  test: 0,
  current: function(a) {
    return {
      set v(x) {
        test = a * x;
        console.log(test);
      }
    };
  },
  current2: function() {
    var _sum = Array.from(arguments).reduce(
      (prev, curr) => {
        return prev + curr
      }, 0);
    return {
      set v(x) {
        test = _sum * x;
        console.log(test);
      }
    };
  },
};

o.current(2).v = 1; //2*1, console => 2
o.current(4).v = 1; //4*1, console => 4
o.current(4).v = 2; //4*2, console => 8
o.current2(1, 1).v = 1; //(1+1)*1, console => 2
o.current2(1, 3).v = 1; //(1+3)*1, console => 4
o.current2(1, 3).v = 2; //(1+3)*2, console => 8
o.current2(...Array(11).keys()).v = 2; //(0+1+2+..+10)*2, console => 110
```